# nested select is not accepting more than one column

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables like this:

> **departments**
>
> dept_no char(4) primary key
>
> dept_name varchar(40) unique
>
> **dept_emp**
>
> emp_no int primary key
>
> dept_no char(4) primary key
>
> from_date date to-date date
>
> **dept_manager**
>
> dept_no char(4) primary key
>
> emp_no int primary key
>
> from_date date
>
> to_date date
>
> **employees**
>
> emp_no int primary key
>
> first_name varchar(14)
>
> last_name varchar(16)

Now I have:

```
select employees.emp_no, employees.first_name,employees.last_name,
departments.dept_name, (select employees.first_name 
from employees where dept_manager.emp_no =employees.emp_no )
from employees,dept_emp ,departments,dept_manager
where (employees.emp_no=dept_emp.emp_no) AND 
(dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no)
LIMIT 300;
```

The second select is to print each employee's manager name.

But when I try to print the last_name of managers it throws an error.

```
select employees.emp_no, employees.first_name,employees.last_name,
    departments.dept_name, (select employees.first_name, **employess.last_name**
    from employees where dept_manager.emp_no =employees.emp_no )
    from employees,dept_emp ,departments,dept_manager
    where (employees.emp_no=dept_emp.emp_no) AND 
    (dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no)
    LIMIT 300;
```

ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Why this error is coming?

Comment: instead of sub query try Join on Employee and record set of sub query.

Comment: @Trinity: I am not able to write it with joins. Just a beginner. If you post the query, it would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how subquery works you should select one column for each of your query to use as a column

```
select employees.emp_no, employees.first_name,employees.last_name,
departments.dept_name, (select employees.first_name
from employees where dept_manager.emp_no =employees.emp_no ) e_first_name,
(select employess.last_name
from employees where dept_manager.emp_no =employees.emp_no ) e_last_name
from employees,dept_emp ,departments,dept_manager
where (employees.emp_no=dept_emp.emp_no) AND 
(dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no)
LIMIT 300;
```

or you can just use `CONCAT()` to merge the names from two columns  like

```
select CONCAT(employees.first_name,'  ',employess.last_name) full_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put 2 columns from subquery in 1 column of your headquery. You should make two subselects, one for each column.